# Why can't I launch Terraria

Tags: technical-issues, terraria

I've just purchased and installed Terraria on my laptop from steam. The first time that I ran the game, there was no issue and it worked perfectly. However, now when I try to launch the game I'm presented with and error message that I can't make anything of. What is this error, and what can I do to fix it and play the game.

[image: error]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a [Steam Post](https://steamcommunity.com/app/105600/discussions/0/626329820875346931/) that someone posted who appears to have had the same error as you.  It looks like they were able to fix it by deleting the `config.dat` inside of the Terraria folder.  It looks like this makes Terraria run in its default resolution and in Windowed mode the next time it launches allowing you make adjustments afterward again to play.